# Image source not readable, Laravel intervention Image

Tags: laravel, intervention

I'm having trouble uploading image and saving path to the databse.
Here is my form: [image]

And my ProductsController: [image]

Error: [image]

I've tried to fixed this for hour but no result. Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for some wrong spelled words

Comment: Please don't post code as *screenshots*!

Comment: Okay. Sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

Try changing 
`Image::make($image)`
to
`Image::make($image->getRealPath());`

Answer (score 0):

To enable exif-support configure PHP with **--enable-exif**

Windows users must enable both the `php_mbstring.dll`and `php_exif.dll` DLL's in php.ini. The `php_mbstring.dll` DLL must be loaded before the php_exif.dll DLL so adjust your php.ini accordingly.

Source php documentation : http://php.net/manual/en/exif.installation.php